# How to enable the configuration settings at my extension for Visual studio code (vscode.workspace.getConfiguration())

Tags: typescript, plugins, vscode-extensions, package.json

I am writing a Visual Studio Code extension and I want to enable the configuration settings of my extension in order to give the opportunity to the user to configure some general settings for the extension. [image: I want to have the name of my extension here at the extension settings]

I added at my `package.json` these lines for the beginning

```
"contributes": {
    "configuration": {
      "title": "Just a title"
    }, 
...
```

and at the `extension.ts` these:

```
const extensionPath = context.extensionPath;
let settingsConfig = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myextension name');
    
settingsConfig.get('myextension name', extensionPath);
```

but it doesn't work. In the Visual Studio Documentation, the only thing mentioned for calling the configuration settings is this:
You can read these values from your extension using `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myExtension')`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `package.json` configuration you provided does not seem to be correct. I have provided a short example below, that you can use to update your configuration in a similar way, where I am adding the boolean setting "mysetting".

```json
"configuration": {
    "title": "Just a title",
    "properties": {
        "myextensionname.mysetting": {
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": "false",
            "description": "This does something"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the setting like this:

```js
const mySetting = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myextensionname').mysetting;
```